# How to move some text down in a li tag?

Tags: html, css

I would like to move down the text inside li of 20px from the top edge box. How to do it with css or css3

http://jsfiddle.net/4pyxM/

I could use `padding-top: 20px;` but I would like to know another way without modifying the html.

```
  <ul id="mylist">
    <li>apple</li>
    <li>banana</li>
    <li>kiwi</li>
</ul>



  #mylist ul {
        position:absolute;
        float:left;
        list-style-type:none;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }

    #mylist li {
        float:left;
        list-style-type:none;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px; // here could be 20px
        width:80px;
        height:80px;
        border:1px solid red;
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you simply looking for this?

```
#mylist li{ 
    padding-top:20px;
}
```

**Edit after your update**

Your styles should be in a separate CSS file from your HTML document. That way you can make changes to your styles without having to edit your HTML.

Comment: this is pretty much the answer

Answer (score 0):

Add `padding-top:10px` and reduce the height of 10px on you `li`:  http://jsfiddle.net/4pyxM/2/

```
#mylist li {
    float:left;
    list-style-type:none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    padding-top:10px;
    width:80px;
    height:70px;
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

**EDIT:** If you want *another way* instead of changing the padding, you can modify the line-height, e.g `line-height:30px`. (the content will be centered in the height of the line).

Answer (score 0):

Change the `padding: 0px` line under the `#myslist li` selector to:

```
padding:10px 0 0 0;
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eNemZ/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can use padding-top for that. i changed your code

 here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4pyxM/1/)

```
 padding: 10px 0 0 0; 
 or
 padding-top: 10px;
```

After your update
You have to only change your css a bit it doesn't require changing HTML

Answer (score 0):

In #mylist li change

```
padding: 0px;
```

TO

```
padding-top: 10px;
```